# Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode returns BadRequest

Tags: azure, azure-automation, powershell-dsc

I am trying to register a DSC Configuration on an Azure VM using the Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode powershell command.

```
Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode   -ResourceGroupName   $p_automationResourceGroupName `
                                        -AutomationAccountName $p_automationAccountName `
                                        -AzureVMResourceGroup $p_tenantResourceGroupName `
                                        -AzureVMName $v_tenantVMName `
                                        -AzureVMLocation $p_tenantResourceGroupLocation `
                                        -NodeConfigurationName "$($p_DSCConfigurationName).localhost" `
                                        -ConfigurationMode ApplyAndMonitor `
                                        -ActionAfterReboot ContinueConfiguration `
                                        -RebootNodeIfNeeded $True -Verbose -Debug
```

I see the following output:

```
DEBUG: ============================ HTTP RESPONSE ============================

Status Code:
BadRequest

Headers:
Pragma                        : no-cache
x-ms-failure-cause            : gateway
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes: 1199
x-ms-request-id               : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-ms-correlation-request-id   : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x-ms-routing-request-id       : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Cache-Control                 : no-cache
Date                          : Thu, 26 Jan 2017 16:15:36 GMT
```

Body:
{
  "error": {
    **"code": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters 'timestamp' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The only supported parameter
s for this template are 'vmName, location, modulesUrl, configurationFunction, registrationKey, registrationUrl, nodeConfigurationName, configurationMode, configurationModeFrequencyMins, refreshFrequencyMins, rebootNodeIfNeeded, actionAfterReboot, allowModule
Overwrite'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for usage details.'."**
  }
}

This command was working fine until recently.

Is the cmdlet broken/updated? Has anyone else seen this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug on our side. Can you please retry and confirm if it works now for you?